# OpenNI 1.5 changes list?

Tags: kinect, openni, primesense

I am using the OpenNI v1.5.2.23, but most samples I find are for 1.0.0.23, so I have to change the code everytime to use the new features, instead of the obsolete ones.

Examples:

```
OldCode: using xn;

NewCode: using OpenNI;

---
OldCode: depth.GetDepthMapPtr().ToPointer();

NewCode: depth.DepthMapPtr.ToPointer();

---
OldCode: depth.GetMapOutputMode();

NewCode: depth.MapOutputMode;

---
OldCode: new Context(@"..\..\data\openniconfig.xml");

NewCode: Context.CreateFromXmlFile(@"..\..\data\openniconfig.xml", out scriptNode);

---

OldCode: Bitmap((int)mapMode.nXRes, (int)mapMode.nYRes ...

NewCode: Bitmap((int)mapMode.XRes, (int)mapMode.YRes ...

---
```

I am looking at the old then I go to newer samples or documentation to find the right new method/class/property, but that is very time-consuming.

So the question is, did someone made any sort of list of what has changed? (the changelog that comes with OpenNI didn't helped me much)